# Swift 2 Database Path Issues

Tags: database, sqlite, swift2

I am following a text tutorial for using databases during iOS app development (http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_8_Application_using_Swift_and_FMDB)

In the following piece of code:

```
     databasePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("contacts.db")
```

An error comes up:

> 'stringByAppendingPathComponent' is unavailable: Use URLByAppendingPathComponent on NSURL instead.

When I try the suggestion:

```
databasePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent("contacts.db")
```

I realize that by making the modification, we are now working with URL's instead of strings, but I don't know what other changes to make to the code

Full code:

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var address: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var phone: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var status: UILabel!

var databasePath = NSString()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,.UserDomainMask, true)

    let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as! String

    databasePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(
    "contacts.db")

    if !filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(databasePath as String) {

        let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

        if contactDB == nil {
            print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }

        if contactDB.open() {
            let sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT)"
            if !contactDB.executeStatements(sql_stmt) {
                print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
            }
            contactDB.close()
        } else {
            print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func saveData(sender: AnyObject) {
    let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

    if contactDB.open() {

        let insertSQL = "INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name, address, phone) VALUES ('\(name.text)', '\(address.text)', '\(phone.text)')"

        let result = contactDB.executeUpdate(insertSQL,
            withArgumentsInArray: nil)

        if !result {
            status.text = "Failed to add contact"
            print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        } else {
            status.text = "Contact Added"
            name.text = ""
            address.text = ""
            phone.text = ""
        }
    } else {
        print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
    }
}

@IBAction func findContact(sender: AnyObject) {
    let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

    if contactDB.open() {
        let querySQL = "SELECT address, phone FROM CONTACTS WHERE name = '\(name.text)'"

        let results:FMResultSet? = contactDB.executeQuery(querySQL,
            withArgumentsInArray: nil)

        if results?.next() == true {
            address.text = results?.stringForColumn("address")
            phone.text = results?.stringForColumn("phone")
            status.text = "Record Found"
        } else {
            status.text = "Record not found"
            address.text = ""
            phone.text = ""
        }
        contactDB.close()
    } else {
        print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are right that `URLByAppendingPathComponent` returns an `NSURL`, but you can always use `absoluteString` to get the path as a `String` and continue working with that String as you already did:

```
let databaseURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent("contacts.db")
let databasePath = databaseURL.absoluteString
```

Or you could take a shortcut and directly build the databasePath without using `NSURL` at all:

```
let databasePath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "database.db"
```